# trying to throw a custom exception to validate email

Tags: php, mysql, oop, email, pdo

Hey so I currently have a form working pretty much how I want except one thing I am trying to make sure the emails that are being entered are valid email addresses I have been told I can use FILTER_VALID_EMAIL but if I do I'm going to get the same error message saying you are already subscribed.

here is where i'm up to at the minute could anybody shed some light on my issue? would be much apreciated! :)

```
            <?php
            // $_POST might be empty even if the request is a POST
            if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
                try {
                    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $subsc_username, $subsc_password);
                    // default error mode is to return FALSE
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }

                $subsc_email = $_POST['sub_email'];

                // Insert form valudes in to query and process sql query
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO subscribers (subsc_email) VALUES (:subsc_email)';

                try {
                    if ( ! filter_var( $subsc_email , FILTER_VALID_EMAIL )) throw new Exception('Invalid Email');


                    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
                    $query->execute(array(

                        ':subsc_email' => $subsc_email,
                    ));
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <strong>Success!</strong> You have been added to our mailing list.</div>'; // Success Message
                        } catch( PDOException $e ) {
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <strong>Error!</strong> You are already subsribed to our mailing list...</div>'; // Error Message
                }
            }
            ?>

            <form method="post" action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sub_email" />
                    <br />
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: It's `filter_var( $subsc_email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )` and not `filter_var( $subsc_email , FILTER_VALID_EMAIL )` try that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error. (missing the letters `ATE` to finish what's supposed to read as `VALIDATE`)

**You need to use:** `filter_var( $subsc_email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )`

*Instead of what you presently have:*

```
filter_var( $subsc_email , FILTER_VALID_EMAIL )
                           ---Missing -^ (ATE)
```

**Replace with the following:**

```
( ! filter_var( $subsc_email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ))
```

- As per the manual: **http://php.net/manual/filter.filters.validate.php**

Comment: Thanks for that seemed had a little typo there. my main problem still occurs though my form disappears when a invalid email such as "fake.fake.com" :S

Comment: You're welcome. Your form "disappears", can you elaborate on that, and do you have a copy of your HTML form also? @user3245801

Comment: I tested your code to much as I could, and I think it's your `throw new exception` that could be playing tricks on you. Try using `if(! filter_var( $subsc_email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )) die('Invalid Email');` instead of `if ( ! filter_var( $subsc_email , FILTER_VALID_EMAIL )) throw new Exception('Invalid Email');` @user3245801 - if the error goes away, then you'll know that's the issue.

Comment: Or try putting `if(!filter_var($subsc_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )) die('Invalid Email');` under `$sql = 'INSERT INTO subscribers (subsc_email) VALUES (:subsc_email)';` @user3245801 - that will stop the process altogether if an invalid email is entered.

Comment: Also, instead of using `if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {` use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` then give your submit button a name like this `<input class="btn btn-success" name="submit" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />` @user3245801

Comment: Boom thats made it state Invalid Email! so thats really cool! thanks!! form still disappears though :S not sure why

Comment: ooh missed your second comment bud let me try that out!

Comment: You're welcome. Now as for your form disappearing, that's probably a CSS issue. Do you have anything special that's supposed to happen when the button is clicked? @user3245801

Comment: Ok, let me know about that (second comment thing). @user3245801

Comment: yep added it and still same behaviour as before form vanishes into thin air :P

Comment: Another thing I'm not sure about is the `catch( PDOException $e )` @user3245801 with the echo statements on top and below of that.

Comment: haha thats probably my retarded coding, so it works in a sense if the email is duplicate it gives error message if the is sucessfuly inserted to DB it gives success message

Comment: I tried to modify it to make it work like you want it, had to remove all the DB-related stuff and got both buttons to appear after submitting. Plus I think the comma at the end of `':subsc_email' => $subsc_email,` shouldn't be there, because there are no other entries after that. Can you try removing it and see? Pretty sure that should work. @user3245801

Comment: comma was another typo yep now removed still same happening.

all error messages are now being displayed when required just this form keeps vanishing on the "Invalid Email" weve talked about before the form remains in place on both others

Comment: Then try this `if(! filter_var( $subsc_email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )){ echo "Invalid Email"; exit(); }` instead of the other version with the `die()` @user3245801 - You can also test that without the `exit();` see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Actually using `if(! filter_var( $subsc_email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )){ echo "Invalid Email";  }` may be your best bet. @user3245801 without the `exit();`

Comment: I set up a quick DB on my side to test it, and you'll need to use the `exit();` after all. Otherwise, even if an invalid email is entered, the process will continue and will enter it in the DB. I'll see what I can do to fix this, but till then, if you can live with it using the `exit();` then cool. @user3245801

Comment: If my answer did fix a lot of things and got you on your way, can you click the `white checkmark` next to my answer, `till it turns green`? That way the question will be closed. In case you're not aware of how SO works, that's how it's done on this Website. @user3245801

Comment: yeah fixed the main issue! :) thanks just that form which disappears now is only issue :)

Comment: i know this may sound stupid but on the invalid email echo i could place my message alert div in there and repeat the form. not exactly elegant but works!

Comment: I was thinking about something like that actually last night, but my head started bobbing, so that said it was time to get some sleep haha! If it works, cool! Keep a copy and play around with it, you'll end up with something better; the work is never done  as they say lol! Cheers @user3245801

Comment: Yeah I did that and it works, just an update though ive chosen not to use die() or exit() as it terminates any execution of scripts on the page so if i was to include this file into another then it killed the parent page. ive opted for a simple return; and it seems to be working :)

Comment: I agree, which I think I did mention that in an earlier comment to that affect. Good going on the `return` ;-) @user3245801